# Trying to determine length of a string using recursion in C++

Tags: c++, string, recursion, counting

```
int count(string s){
    if(s == "")
      return 0;
    if(s.length == 1)
      return 1;
    return 1 + count() //This is what I can't figure out. How to traverse the string.
    //I just need a hint, not a full on answer.
}
```

I dont know how to traverse a string.

Comment: Hint: The size of a string is 1 + the size of the string with the first (or last) character removed. The size of an empty string is zero.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me.. now what you probably want to do on the second last line: return 1 + count(s.substr(0, s.length() - 1));

Comment: Yeah it's homework. Nothing special but it's bugging me pretty good.

Comment: are you sure then that you need to use `std::string` vs `char*`? `if(s.length == 1)` looks almost like cheating :)

Comment: You use string's `length` method which already returns size. What's the point of this exercise?

Comment: That's what i thought, why use recursive to count a string length when there's already a built in function to do that. The prof wants to familiarize us with recursion in all its glory. The good and bad i guess...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: use [`substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) in your recursion.

Also, you have two base cases. One of them has three issues:

1. it has a syntax error in it;
2. it relies on being able to compute the length of the string (which is what your function is supposed to do);
3. it is unnecessary given that you have the other base case.

Comment: I put the two base cases because they said if the string is empty return 0, and then i put the base case of length == 1 if it was > 0.

Comment: @user1893303 you could use 0 as your base case.

Comment: I removed the length() == 0 case.

Comment: @user1893303: That's exactly the wrong thing to do. What if I call your function with an empty string?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you example makes any sense, you use `length` which already returns length in your calculation. If I were your tutor, I wouldn't have accepted this as a valid solution.

You probably need to use `const char*`

```
int count(const char* s){
    if(*s == '\0')
      return 0;
    return 1 + count(s + 1);
}
```

Comment: You don't _need_ `const char*`, not even `char*`.

Comment: The problem is not that the string knows its length, but that the OP uses it as a base case.

Comment: From other examples i found they all used chars but the requirement for the question was to use a string data type. I know its silly to count the length in recursion when all you have to due is use length() function but i think the prof wants us to at least experience string recursion.

Comment: @irrelephant, what is the point of calculating length of the `std::string` if it already knows it? I guess his assignment sounds like `calculate string size recursively` where `string` is meant to be c-string, not `std::string`

Comment: @user1893303, did he explicitly say `std::string` or just "string data type"? The latter probably means that you need `const char*`

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is to traverse a string, I suggest using an iterator (see `std::string::begin`).

```
template<typename It>
int count(It const begin, It const end)
{
  return (begin != end ? count(begin + 1, end) + 1 : 0);
}

int count(std::string const& s)
{
  return count(s.begin(), s.end());
}
```

Comment: How does that use recursion?

Comment: @JanDvorak: if the argument to the function is an iterator (along with the "end" iterator), it is recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would want to use `substr`.

Answer (score 0):

I know you want a C++ solution, but still. Sometimes C is better than C++.

```
int count(const char *s)
{
  if(*s == 0)
    return 0;
  else return 1 + count(++s);
};
```

Call as count(str.c_str()).

Answer (score 0):

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  main(){
  char str1[100];
  gets(str1);
  int i=0;i=len(str1,i);printf(" \nlength of string is %d",i);
  }
  int len(char s1[],int i) {
  printf("\n%c",s1[i]);
  int sum=0,count =1; 
  if(s1[i] == '\0') return 0;
  else
  return (count += len(s1,++i));
  }
```